# Desktop Crashes and Bluescreens issues. Can't spot the issue. (PC gamer so will mention games)

Tags: windows-10, bsod, crash, gaming

I've been having this issue with my PC a while now (almost 5 years) and still can't figure out what's wrong with it nor fix it.

Issues:

- There are times where desktop, window explorer/folders, will stop responding and I will end up restarting the PC where it will be stuck at loading (Windows logo). So I will be forced to shut down and start (x3)
- Sometimes I get blue screen, I just forgot when and what       app/game I was using.
- There are times when I play a certain game and the PC will shutdown. For example, when I used to play the game Modern Warfare II (MWII/CoD), it couldn't handle the graphics for some reason. It crashes my PC and shuts down. Then I tried some fixes which I forgot what I did (in order) but my friend already changed the motherboard and some tech guy online advised me to change the slot of my RAMs which kind of improved the performance (less crash) but then I get bad lags in CoD.

Right now I'm trying to play the game "Palworld" and PC crashes and shuts down. I tried it again and it won't stay on for 5 minutes when the game is on. This happened 3 times. I lowered the graphics to "Very low" and I am able to play up to a couple hours (or maybe in-game situation) before it crashes again.

Some friend and the random tech guy (online) I talked to tried to diagnose my PC issues (by reading my bluescreen log) and thought it was my RAM. Then I got a new pair of RAM and still doing the same behavior.

Errors/Crashes:

[image: Errors/Crashes]

CPU Motherboard GPU:

[image: CPU Motherboard GPU]

Comment: Could be CPU overheating, could be GPU overheating, could be under-rated power supply. You need to post an actual list of your computer specifications, preferably as text. The image you linked basically only lists the processor and quantity of RAM which isn't much use. What GPU do you have? What is your power supply? What motherboard? What slots is the memory inserted in? What temperatures do components get up to? (You can use a program such as [HWinfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/) to see temperatures. You can [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: Enable crash dumps, and open one of the dump files with WhoCrashed. If it's a driver issue, you'll find the answer in there. Otherwise, it's like Mokubai said; overheating or lack of capacity from the PSU

Comment: Updated. Took a screenshot again since I'm not sure which text I should be copying haha.

Comment: GameInput Service implies a faulty piece of hardware, or a bad driver